# Need progress bar at the time of unzip in SWT wizard by java

Tags: swt, progress-bar, eclipse-rcp, unzip, wizard

I have implement SWT wizard appliation, In this application i performed unzip file programatically and i need a progress bar during unzip. Please find the below code for unzip,

```
 public static void extract(File zipfile, File outdir)
      {
        try
        {
          ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream (zipfile));
          ZipEntry entry;
          String name, dir;
          while ((entry = zin.getNextEntry()) != null)
          {
            name = entry.getName();
            if( entry.isDirectory() )
            {
              mkdirs(outdir,name);
              continue;
            }
            /* this part is necessary because file entry can come before
             * directory entry where is file located
             * i.e.:
             *   /foo/foo.txt
             *   /foo/
             */
            dir = dirpart(name);
            if( dir != null )
              mkdirs(outdir,dir);

            extractFile(zin, outdir, name);

          }

          zin.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
```

At the wizard page i call this method like this,

```
    btnUnzip.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {

            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event event) {

                    File file = new File(text.getText());
                    File file1 = new File(textToSaveUnzipFile.getText());
                    UnzipUtility.extract(file, file1);
      }
   }
```

Comment: What do you mean be 'SWT wizard'? Is this using the JFace `Wizard`/`WizzrdDialog`/`WizardPage` classes (which have a built in progress monitor) or is this just plain `SWT`?

Comment: using wizardDialog in SWT project

Comment: Thanks for your reply,If i extend WizardPage class, how is possible.

Comment: The setNeedsProgressMonitor must be in the Wizard. The getContainer call can be in a WizardPage or the Wizard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a JFace `Wizard` you can use the built in progress monitor in the wizard.

In the Constructor of your Wizard class call:

```
setNeedsProgressMonitor(true);
```

To show progress call

```
getContainer().run(true, true, runnable);
```

This call can be in the `Wizard` or a `WizardPage`.

where `runnable` is a class implementing `IRunnableWithProgress`. The `run` method of this class will look something like:

```
@Override
public void run(final IProgressMonitor monitor)
  throws InterruptedException
{
  monitor.beginTask("Title", .. number of work steps ..);

  try
   {
     while (not finished) {
        ... do a small amount of work

        // Update progress
        monitor.worked(1);
     }
   }
  finally
   {
     monitor.done();
   }
}
```

Comment: I have question reagarding progress bar , if i set work steps in begin task 100 and after that i used monitor.worked(100). at the time of unzip progress bar showing 100 before completed the unzip functionality.

Comment: If you want progress to show you have to do the work in small bits calling 'worked' after each bit. If you can't do this you can't have animated progress.